# Create a List of All Files Located In Every Common Subdirectory

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to writing in C# and .NET for that matter, and would like to make my program run more efficiently so I'm wondering if someone could help me out here.  In a nutshell, my program goes through a series of Excel files and copies data into them.  This is all working fine, but I would like to make it even more efficient.  As of now I **make a list of all the Excel file paths in the directory Clients like this:**

`listClientExcelPaths = new List<String>(Directory.GetFiles(PATH_Root + PATH_Clients, "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories));`

I then remove the Excel files from the list which are either temporary or obviously incorrect in some way and then cycle through the `listClientExcelFiles` and process each file.  When I open the Excel file up I make sure the contents of the Excel file is what I want and if it isn't then I close it.

Now this is all well and good, however in order to make the processing a little more efficient I would like only the Excel files that are in the Admin folder under every client.  So the directory structure of every client folder is such: `ClientName\Admin`.

**My questions are:** What would the most efficient way of doing this be?  I'm thinking going through each path in the list and removing the path that doesn't include Admin?  Could anyone give me an example of this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is fine. If you have no problem using LINQ, then the task is a one-liner like this:

```
var paths = new List<string>
{
    @"a\b\admin\c",
    @"x\y\z\",
    @"ddd\ggg\hhh\admin",
    @"zzz\yyy\rrr"
};

var filteredPaths = paths.Where (p => p.ToLower().Contains("admin")).ToList();
```

Output is:

```
a\b\admin\c 
ddd\ggg\hhh\admin
```

Comment: yeah I've just been learning LINQ and it seems pretty straightforwards.  Thanks!